# Concatenar entero y cadena en un temaplate de Django

Tags: html, django, template

Buenos días,

el problema que tengo es que quiero concatenar un int con un string en un template de Django, pero cuando lo intento, me retorna un valor vació. Este es mi código:

```
{% with "object_"|add:obj.id as check_id %}
El objeto es {{check_id}}
{% endwith %}
```

Al parecer este codigo no funciona porque obj.id es un entero y "object_" es una cadena. Me gustaría saber cual es la forma correcta de agregar un entero a una cadena dentro del template.

Aclaro que ***obj***, es un objeto que paso desde la vista y cuando muestro solamente ese valor, si obtengo el id de la siguiente forma:

```
{{obj.id}}
```

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No funciona porque el filtro [`add`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/templates/builtins/#add) convierte (o trata de convertir) ambos valores a números. Falla porque no puede hacerlo con `"object_"`.

Tienes varias alternativas:

### Aternativa 1. Solo presentación.

Si quieres unir la cadena, solo por cuestiones de presentación, entonces no necesitas ningún tipo de lógica, solo usa el valor junto a la cadena.

```
{# Alternativa 1 #}
El objeto es object_{{ obj.id }}
```

### Alternativa 2. Parámetro en una URL

Si quieres usar el valor como parámetro de una URL para pasarlo a una función, puedes prescindir del texto y usar solo el número:

```
# En urls.py
(r'^(?P<check_id>\d+)$', 'check_id_view')

{# en una plantilla #}
<a href="{% url 'check_id_view' check_id=obj.id %}">object_{{ obj.id }}</a>
```

### Alternativa 3. Un filtro

Puedes evitar colocar lógica del negocio en la plantilla usando un filtro personalizado (ver [la documentación](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/custom-template-tags/#)).

```
# En templatetags/filtros.py
from django import template


register = template.Library()

@register.filter(name='check')
def check(id):
    try: return "object_%d" % id
    except KeyError: return ""
```

y se usa como cualquier otro filtro

```
{# Alternativa 3 #}
El objeto es {{ obj.id|check }}
```

> No he probado el código, pero te da una idea de que puedes hacer.

Comment: Muchas gracias, he optado por la opción 3, es un poco engorrosa, pero sirve muy bien a lo que estoy buscando hacer.

Comment: Excelente elección. La propia documentación del proyecto recomienda [**separar la lógica de la presentación**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/misc/design-philosophies/#separate-logic-from-presentation).